# doctrine manyToMany Query on Inverse Side

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I've got 2 entity with Many To Many Relationship. They are Mapped correctly, both sides.

When I'm querying the inverse side with an Entity of the Owning side I've got the following error:

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in /var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1528

I'm using the "built-in" doctrine findBy Methods, in this case: `"findByInverseSide($InverseSideEntity)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this By creating a DQL query with Left Join on the InverseSide of The Table:

EX:

```
...
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
        $qb->leftJoin('q.inverseSide', 'i')
            ->where('i.id = :inverseSide_id')
            ->setParameter('inverseSide_id', $inverseSide_id);
...
```